# If 'ять' sounds like 'yat' then what does 'ят' sound like?

Tags: произношение

If have just started to learn Russian and have come across the fact that 'ь' remains silent but changes the sound of the letter that comes before it (I think). Please can someone give me an example of how e.g. ять and ят would sound different.

Comment: I think your question will be clearer with a different example. You see, ять is the name of an obsolete Cyrillic letter (`ѣ`, pronounced the same as `е` by the time it was abolished), so at first the question seems to be about something else. Would any pair of examples with/without `ь` do instead, or are you specifically asking about the unusual behaviour of `ь` in some verb endings, many of which are actually `-ять`/`-ят`?

Comment: Any example would be fine. (I only chose ять and ят because this is the only case I have come across thus far).

Comment: It is called a palatalization. Many Russian consonants have two variants: normal and palatalized ("hard" and "soft").

Comment: It's really hard to show the difference in pronunciation between hard and soft consonants in written text. Watch this [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH2XShG2HHs) and you'll hear it.

Comment: Are there no English examples like the t in ять sounds like that in ... and the t in ят sounds like that in ...?

Comment: No. It's like there are no Russian examples for both kinds of English "th".

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification I correct: there are surely a lot of English examples for hard consonants but no examples (or very hard to find) for their soft counterparts to hear the difference.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification, what is your native language? Or, if it is English, are you familiar with any other languages? In English there is no palatalization, but in many other languages it exists.

Comment: @Lara Yes I am English, and unfortunately I don't know any other languages.

Comment: I have found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roevsN1zBl4 which explains it nicely

Comment: @Lara in English there is palatalization, it is just not phonemic (varies from dialect to dialect).

Comment: @Quantum spaghettification there are, but in English this differs between dialects. Also I am not sure whether English has soft "t" in any dialect. P.S. I have just listened to Google translate, and the English speaker pronounces soft "t" in "tea" so there is English example.

Comment: @Anixx, any examples? I know only that in some Irish dialects they substitute [t] with [ʃ] in words ending with "-it" (like "fruit"), and with [t͡ʃ] in words like "tree" or "tumor", and maybe some others. I'm not sure, if this can be called palatalization, but it probably comes from Irish (Gaelic) language, where there is actual palatalization, similar to Russian. There is reverse process, as well: nowadays in some dialects of Irish language palatalized [t] and [d] are substituted by [t͡ʃ] and [d͡ʒ], borrowed sounds from English, which originally were not present in Irish.

Comment: @Lara http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/why-ipa-does-not-indicate-soft-consonants-in-english

Comment: 'ять' does not sounds like 'yat'. 'ят' does. :)

Comment: relevant link for English speaker - http://therusblog.com/2012/02/18/palatalization-in-russian/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do sound different as long as they are written so:

> Брат // brother
>
> Брать // to take
>
> Мат // mat (gym)
>
> Мать // mother

If you need to listen to feel the difference, use Google Translate - there's a button to read your text aloud.

Answer (score 4):

If you're British, then you probably already use a soft [t] in the word **tune**, as compared to how we Americans say the same word. You basically say **тюн** and we say **тун**. If you can, isolate the first consonant in both pronunciations, and you will get the gist of what happens phonetically when you pronounce a Russian soft consonant. Basically, you're producing the target sound, but with your tongue wanting to form a [y] sound at the same time. Very often, English speakers who are learning Russian get away with just saying a full [y] after the target sound, which is wrong. The idea is to produce the target consonant WHILE the tongue is in the [y] position as one articulation.

BTW, you can do the same for -дь- with **dune** (Brit. **дюн** Am. **дун**)

Comment: Honestly, the British pronounce тьюн, дьюн rather than тюн, дюн. This is how ABYY Lingvo pronounces and according the English reading rules we were taught.

Comment: And what the American speaker pronounces I would transliterate as дюн. http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ru/Translate/en-ru/dune

Comment: Far be it from me to contradict English pronunciation rules taught in Russian schools, but no American speaker would ever say дюн, that is purely British. An American using that pronunciation would be considered very affected and pedantic indeed - like Frasier, for example. And I'm sorry, but I can't consider the recordings on ABYY Lingvo the last word in English pronunciation. Here is a good comparison of both pronunciations from the Cambridge Dictionary with IPA: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/sand-dune and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tune

Comment: following your link, the American says сэн дюн, the British says сан дьюн.

Answer (score 0):

i can supply an explanation involving spanish, if of course you have some knowledge of it.

the russian sign "ь" changing the sounding of previous letter in the similar way as "~" upper sign changes sounding of simple "n" in spanish. (ñ=нь, Ñ=Нь. one sample of transliteration - niño=ниньо, try in cyrillics this word in google search)
however unlike spanish, russian "ь" sign may change the pronuncation into similar way of almost any consonant that it follows after.
so "ять" is not actually [yat], but rather [yat'] and "ят" is then [yat]. note the appearing apostrophe in the first one.

if you don't have access to some spanish source, then there is also may be an explanation. try to imangine how the previous consonant would sound if it would stand before the i/y letter in two words combination where the second is starting with i/y, as in phrase, got you - gotcha(got'cha). as you see the "t" in "got" have changed. in the same way all the letters with "ь" following are changed in russian.

Answer (score -4):

Ять is made of two sounds: я [ya] and ть [t']. Second  sound, soft T, you can hear in a few english words such as tea, terminate (first t), estimate (first t). Russian examples are мать, тигр, тяжба. But remember that [t'] in russian is much softer than in english.
Ят is also made of я [ya], but here T is hard and pronounced like [t]. For example, in english train, track, tomb, in russian твердь, торг, трамвай.
Also, like it is advised above, watch some youtube videos (cs:go with russian teammates, they swear a lot, and swearing in russian is the best way to understand pronunciation of ять), or listen to google translator.

Comment: The sound [i] does not palatize the consonant before it in English. Both "t"s in "estimate" and all other "t"s in "tea" and "terminate" are the same sound which is different from "ть".

Comment: But they aren't the same. Do you think [t] in the "tea" and [t] in the "tree" are same? Hell no. And i wrote, that in russian [t'] is softer than in english. And btw i'm russian, so i know exactly how ять is pronounced.

Comment: That's the thing - having Russian as native language you think that those "t"s are different because they are different in Russian (as in f.e. in "трос" and "тигр"). And saying "softer" is not useful for a person who is not familiar with the concept of "softness". It's like if somebody would say a Russian that French "è" is "opener" than "é" - _"What? Opener? Should I open my mouth more now or what does that mean??"_ And BTW the question is not about pronouciation of "ять" but about the difference between soft and hard consonants.

Comment: I'm just saying, that in russian those sounds are really differ from each other, and giving examples of sounds in english that, in my honorable russian opinion, are closest to the russian "ять". Sorry, if in english there is no difference between my examples, for me there is a huge difference in their pronunciation.

Comment: ять is made of three sounds, not two.

Comment: @Alex.S I have just used Google translate and they pronounce soft "t" in "tea".

Comment: @Anixx I have just used Google translate and they pronounce two identical "t"s in "take tea" :)

Comment: @Alex.S they don't. You are seemingly confusing phonology and phonetics. Yes the both sounds are the same phonemes in English, but they are different phonemes in Russian. Also they pronounce soft consonants in other words as well: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/why-ipa-does-not-indicate-soft-consonants-in-english